# Python list of dicts - find closest 4 entries in list to the new entry

Tags: python

I have a list of dictionaries:

```
members = [ 
{'name': 'Fred', 'age': 22}, 
{'name': 'John', 'age': 25},
{'name': 'Adamn', 'age': 33},
{'name': 'Lily', 'age': 17},
{'name': 'Susy', 'age': 19},
{'name': 'Frank', 'age': 42},
{'name': 'Adam', 'age': 38},
{'name': 'Jose', 'age': 18}, 
{'name': 'Mikey', 'age': 14},
{'name': 'Shelby', 'age': 27} 
]
```

I then have a new member joining and i would like to pair them with 4 people, the closest members in age.

```
new_member = {'name': 'Rob', 'age': 23}
```

The return of this would pick out Fred (22), John (25), Susy (19), Shelby (27) because they are the closest in age to Rob.  My approach seems to be returning an infinite loop and not the right results.  I also have a feeling there is a more elegant way to go about this that i'm looking to understand/learn.  But this is what i have so far:

```
new_list = sorted(members, key=lambda k: k['age']) 
for row in newlist:
  diff = row['age'] - new_member['age']
  row.update({'diff':diff})

closest = []

for i, mem in enumerate(newlist):
  if i == 0:
    closest.insert(0, mem)
  elif i > 0:
    for row in closest:
      if row['diff'] < mem['diff']:
        closest.insert(0, mem)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not sort by the *difference* in ages instead?

```
closest = sorted(
    members, key=lambda x: abs(x['age'] - new_member['age'])
)[:4]
```

Smaller the difference => closer they are in age.

```
print(closest)
[{'age': 22, 'name': 'Fred'},
 {'age': 25, 'name': 'John'},
 {'age': 19, 'name': 'Susy'},
 {'age': 27, 'name': 'Shelby'}
]
```

Keep in mind that you'll be assigning the *original* record objects to `closest`, so if you end up modifying those objects, `members` will also reflect these changes. You can add a `copy` call beforehand for that case: `from copy import deepcopy; closest = deepcopy(....)`